# Pegar valor de chave definida com hífen

Tags: php, xml

Estou tentando acessar o valor da chave url-autenticacao, mas apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant autenticacao - assumed 'autenticacao' in
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[versao] => 1.3.0
[id] => 123
)

[tid] => 10017348980132951001
[dados-pedido] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[numero] => 123
[valor] => 1000
[moeda] => 986
[data-hora] => 2014-04-30T23:54:07.892-03:00
[descricao] => [origem:::1]
[idioma] => PT
[taxa-embarque] => 0
)

[forma-pagamento] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[bandeira] => visa
[produto] => 1
[parcelas] => 1
)

[status] => 0
[url-autenticacao] => https://qasecommerce.cielo.com.br/web/index.cbmp?id=789b9ef9858bf2aba2751df3f306424a
)
Tentei usar o echo $xml->url-autenticacao mas apresentou a mensagem de erro descrito acima.
```

Como faço para conseguir o valor dessa chave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os elementos do `SimpleXMLElement` obedecem às convenções de nomes de variáveis do *PHP*, e o `-` não é um caractere permitido.

Neste caso, use `{` e `}` para encapsular o nome destes elementos:

```
echo $xml->{'url-autenticacao'};
```

Esta forma também pode ser usada quando se quer utilizar o valor de variáveis:

```
$elemento = 'pipoca';
echo $xml->{$elemento};
```

Veja mais [exemplos](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexml.examples-basic.php) no [manual online do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: Bacco, obrigado pela resposta!